# How to build with Webpack and upload files using SFTP in CircleCI?

Tags: continuous-integration, devops, circleci

I really like CircleCI but the documentation is not so clear, to be honest. I have a Webpack and package.json to run a build output this works if I only run the node image, but combining the Webpack build and uploading to my SFTP fails.

How can I run two different tasks?

My config.yml:

```
version: 2
jobs:

  build:
    machine:
      - image: circleci/classic:latest
    docker:
      - image: circleci/node:10.16
    branches:
          only:
            - develop
    working_directory:  ~/repo
    steps:
      - checkout

      # Download and cache dependencies
      - restore_cache:
          keys:
            - v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
            # fallback to using the latest cache if no exact match is found
            - v1-dependencies-

      - run: yarn install

      - save_cache:https://bitbucket.org/Blaat/bitbucket-pipeline-test/src/90ad67cdcb35/.circleci/config.yml?at=develop
          paths:
            - node_modules
          key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}

      # run tests!
      - run: yarn test-build

      - run:
          name: Install LFTP
          command: |
            sudo apt-get update;
            sudo apt-get install lftp;
      - checkout
      - run:
          name: Send Via SFTP
          command: lftp sftp://${username}:${password}@${hostname} -e "mirror -v -R --exclude src/ --exclude webpack/ --exclude .babelrc --exclude .browserslistrc --exclude .eslintrc --exclude .gitignore --exclude .prettierrc --exclude .stylelintignore --exclude .stylelintrc --exclude bitbucket-pipelines.yml --exclude env.json --exclude yarn.lock  --exclude .git/ --exclude package.json --exclude .circleci/ ./ ${site_name}/wp-content/themes/${theme}; quit"
```

Error I get:

```
#!/bin/sh -eo pipefail
# Unable to parse YAML
# mapping values are not allowed here
#  in 'string', line 26, column 16:
#               paths:
#                    ^
# 
# -------
# Warning: This configuration was auto-generated to show you the message above.
# Don't rerun this job. Rerunning will have no effect.
false
Exited with code 1
```

Comment: The issue here is not that CircleCI's docs are unclear - it's just you have given them a config file in malformed YAML. You can validate YAML files [at this site](https://yaml-online-parser.appspot.com/), and it gives the same error.

Comment: @halfer Why do I get this error?

Comment: It appears that your latest edit has invalidated an answer below. Please don't do that! It is OK - up to a point - to edit new material into questions if they are related (using an "Edit" addendum). So the error about "The schema/shape of the YAML is incorrect" may be OK. The other error about "Fatal error: Host key verification failed" probably deserves a new question, since it is a very different issue.

Comment: Thanks for the advice won't do that anymore! appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's start by fixing your current error.

The error is happening on the following block of code.

```
- save_cache:https://bitbucket.org/Blaat/bitbucket-pipeline-test/src/90ad67cdcb35/.circleci/config.yml?at=develop
      paths:
        - node_modules
      key: v1-dependencies-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
```

The error occurs because the command is malformed - in particular, the url that appears after **save_cache** shouldn't be there.

Can you please replace that block of code with the stock nodejs save cache code from the CircleCi docs here: https://circleci.com/docs/2.0/language-javascript/

```
- save_cache: # special step to save the dependency cache
      key: dependency-cache-{{ checksum "package.json" }}
      paths:
        - ./node_modules
```

Rerun the job after fixing that error, and we can see what other issues may exist in the code.

Comment: Sorry, for the late reply Parzie. I will try it know and let you know in a second. Thanks for the advice.

Comment: I have edited my answer and changed as you told me to do. I am having a different error now. I need to run NODE and SFTP afterwards but for some reason, it's not working.

Comment: I have removed "machine line" it fails on the last step when trying to upload using SFTP:

cd `Blaat/wp-content/themes/blaat-theme' [Delaying before reconnect: 4]  
cd `Blaat/wp-content/themes/blaat-theme' [Delaying before reconnect: 3]  
cd `Blaat/wp-content/themes/blaat-theme' [Delaying before reconnect: 2]  
cd `Blaat/wp-content/themes/blaat-theme' [Delaying before reconnect: 1]  
cd `Blaat/wp-content/themes/blaat-theme' []                              
mirror: Fatal error: Host key verification failed.

1 error detected
Exited with code 1

Comment: @Galanthus: excellent, you are now one step further! Good stuff, your problem is solved.

Comment: You appear to have a new problem, so I would suggest researching that with the thoroughness that new problems deserve, and then asking a new question if you get stuck. The critical part of the new error is "Fatal error: Host key verification failed", which may be useful in your search terms.

Comment: Thank you will do.

Comment: @Galanthus Since my solution solved your initial problem, can you please accept it?